Shouldn't these two tags be synonyms?
Shouldn't tag irs and tag interest-rate-swap be synonyms?

They should be and as of now they are.

Unless of course "irs" refers to taxation ;-) Except whether this should be an appropriate venue for tax discussions is perfectly moot.
